# What is the formula for the Wu class $v_6$ in terms of Stiefel-Whitney classes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Please let me know what is the formula for the Wu class $v_6$ in terms of Stiefel-Whitney classes.

Many thanks.

Comment: The first three Wu classes are computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/800804/39599). To see the calculation of the fourth and fifth Wu classes, follow the link in my answer. If you understand these, you can calculate $\nu_n$ for any $n$ although it becomes computationally more intense as $n$ increases.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, I am implementing your procedure using Mathematica.  I am obtaining an expression for $v_6$.  Please, could you checked it?  Many thanks.

Comment: How did you use Mathematica to compute this?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, many thanks for your indications and checks.  The Mathematica Code was added in my answer.  Please let me know what do you think.  All the best.

Comment: Does this really need a new answer every time you observe something new? That seems more appropriate for personal notes or a blog.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the procedure showed by  Michael Albanese; and implemented it with Mathematica I am obtaining

$$v_{{6}}={w_{{1}}}^{2}{w_{{2}}}^{2}+{w_{{1}}}^{3}w_{{3}}+w_{{1}}w_{{2}}
w_{{3}}+{w_{{3}}}^{2}+{w_{{1}}}^{2}w_{{4}}+w_{{2}}w_{{4}}
$$

Please let me know if such result is correct.

Many thanks.

The Mathematica Code:

```
rule1 = {Sq[i_, a_ + b_] :> Sq[i, a] + Sq[i, b]};

rule2 = {Sq[0, x_] :> x};
rule3 = {Sq[i_, v[i_]] :> v[i]^2};
rule4 = {Sq[i_, 0] :> 0};



W[k_] := Simplify[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(13\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(13\)]If[i > j, 0, 1]*
     If[i + j == k, 1, 0]*Sq[i, v[j]]\)\)]


W[1] /. rule2 /. rule3


rule5 := {v[1] :> w[1]}


W[2] /. rule2 /. rule3 /. rule5

rule6 := {v[2] :> w[2] + w[1]^2}



rule7 := {Sq[1, x_^2] :> 0};


rule7A := {Sq[1, x_^4] :> 0};




Sq[i_, w[j_]] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(t = 0\), \(i\)]\(w[i - t]*w[j + t]*
   Mod[Binomial[j - i + t - 1, t], 2]\)\)

Sq[k_, x_*y_] := \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(13\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(13\)]If[i + j == k, 1, 
     0]*Sq[i, x]*Sq[j, y]\)\)


rule7B := {Sq[k_, x_^(n_)] :> \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(13\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(13\)]If[i + j == k, 1, 
        0]*Sq[i, x^\((n - 1)\)]*Sq[j, x]\)\)};

w[0] := 1;

W[3] /. rule2 /. rule6 /. rule1 /. rule7

Solve[w[3] == v[3] + w[1] w[2] + w[3], v[3]] /. -1 -> 1


rule8 := {v[3] :> w[1]*w[2]};


rule9 := {(x_ + y_)^2 :> x^2 + y^2}





rule10 := {(2*x_) :> 0}

rule10A := {(3*x_) :> x}
rule10B := {(7*x_) :> x}
rule10C := {(12*x_) :> 0}

Simplify[W[4] /. rule2 /. rule3 /. rule8 /. rule6 /. rule9] /. rule10

Solve[w[4] == v[4] + w[1]^4 + w[2]^2 + w[1] w[3], v[4]] /. -1 -> 1


rule11 := {v[4] :> w[1]^4 + w[2]^2 + w[1] w[3] + w[4]}



Expand[W[5] /. rule11 /. rule8 /. rule2 /. rule1 /. rule1 /. rule1 /. 
     rule10 /. rule10A] /. rule7 /. rule7A

Solve[w[5] == 
   v[5] + w[1]^3 w[2] + w[1] w[2]^2 + w[1]^2 w[3] + w[1] w[4] + w[5], 
  v[5]] /. -1 -> 1

rule12 := {v[5] :> w[1]^3 w[2] + w[1] w[2]^2 + w[1]^2 w[3] + w[1] w[4]}

Expand[Expand[
             W[6] /. rule12 /. rule11 /. rule8 /. rule2 /. rule1 /. 
                  rule1 /. rule1 /. rule2 /. rule7 /. rule10] /. 
            rule10A /. rule10 /. rule10B /. rule7B /. rule7B /. 
       rule7 /. rule2 /. rule7B] /. rule10 /. rule10A /. rule10C

Solve[w[6] == 
   v[6] + w[1]^2 w[2]^2 + w[1]^3 w[3] + w[1] w[2] w[3] + w[3]^2 + 
    w[1]^2 w[4] + w[2] w[4] + w[6]] /. -1 -> 1
```

Comment: I just did it by hand and I got the same answer.

Comment: Now that you have $\nu_6$, it seems like you can add this as a new rule and then solve for $\nu_7$. Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, you are right.  In the Mathematica notebook, ·$v_1, v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5, v_6$ were computed successively and then them were added successively as  new rules.  In order to compute  $v_7$ is necessary to know $v_6$.  I will try to compute $v_7$ and I will post the result.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, the expression for $v_7$ was posted.  Please check it.  Many thanks.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, in the preprint  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4461.pdf, in the equation (2.8), appears the expression for $v_6$; but the equation (2.8) has a typo. In the equation (2.8) appears $w_3w_1 ^2$ but it must be $w_3w_1^3$ . Do you agree?

Comment: Yes. I think it is just a typo as $w_3w_1^2$ does not even have degree six.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, please look the equation (2.7) in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4461.pdf, it gives a very nice method to compute all the Wu classes.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Mathematica Code I am obtaining

$$v_{{7}}={w_{{1}}}^{2}w_{{2}}w_{{3}}+w_{{1}}{w_{{3}}}^{2}+w_{{1}}w_{{2}
}w_{{4}}
$$

Please let me know if such result is correct.

Comment: I did it by hand and I got the same answer.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, please look  below a possible application of  the formula for $v_7$.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As an application of the formula for $v_7$, we will prove the following lemma:

Let $Y^{15}$ be an orientable fifteen-manifold.  Then we have
$w_{15}(Y^{15}) =w_{14}(Y^{15})=w_{13}(Y^{15}) = 0 $.

Proof.  From the properties of the Wu classes we obtain for $Y^{15}$ that

$$\left\{ v_{{8}}=0,v_{{9}}=0,v_{{10}}=0,v_{{11}}=0,v_{{12}}=0,v_{{13}}=0,v_{{14}}=0,v_{{15}}=0 \right\}$$

Now from the Wu’s formula, we derive that
$$w_{{15}}=0$$
$$w_{{14}}={v_{{7}}}^{2}$$
$$w_{{13}}={\it Sq}^{{6}} \left( v_{{7}} \right) $$

From other side we know that

$$v_{{7}}={w_{{1}}}^{2}w_{{2}}w_{{3}}+w_{{1}}{w_{{3}}}^{2}+w_{{1}}w_{{2}
}w_{{4}}
$$

but given that $Y^{15}$ is orientable, it is to say $w_1 =0$; we obtain that $v_7=0$.
For hence we have that

$$w_{{15}}=0$$
$$w_{{14}}={v_{{7}}}^{2} = 0^2 = 0$$
$$w_{{13}}={\it Sq}^{{6}} \left( v_{{7}} \right)= {\it Sq}^{{6}} \left( 0\right)=0 $$

And then our lemma is proved.

Do you agree?

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Recall that $w_{13} = \operatorname{Sq}^6(\nu_7) + \operatorname{Sq}^5(\nu_8) + \operatorname{Sq}^4(\nu_9) + \operatorname{Sq}^3(\nu_{10}) + \operatorname{Sq}^2(\nu_{11}) + \operatorname{Sq}^1(\nu_{12}) + \operatorname{Sq}^0(\nu_{13})$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese,  using the property              
$v_i = 0$ for  $2i > 15$ we have that $w_{13}= Sq^6(v_7)$.  Do you agree?

Comment: Of course. I missed that, then yes, this looks right.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, a similar lemma is valid in dimensions 3, 7, 11, 15.   In the case of dim = 19, it is necessary to compute $v_9$, but I think that $v_9 =0$ when  $w_1 = 0$.  I am conjecturing that the lemma is valid in general for dim = 4 i + 3 for i =0,1,2,3.... Do you agree?

Comment: Yes. Your conjecture is true.

Answer (score 1):

A direct method for the computation of the Wu classes is presented in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1109.4461.pdf

The following paragraph shows the method.

[image]
The equation (2.7) is implemented via Maple using the package Schubert, according with the following code:

> restart:with(schubert); DIM:=15: b:=bundle(15,c):  eq:=todd(b):
>   aux:={c1=w[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fai6x.jpg),c2=w[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9I6J.jpg),c3=w[3],c4=w[4],c5=w[5],c6=w[6],c7=w[7],c8=w[8],c9=w[9],c10=w[10],c11=w[11],c12=w[12],c13=w[13],c14=w[14],c15=w[15]};
>   for i from 1 to 11 do
>   print(v[i]=subs(w[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fai6x.jpg)=w[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fai6x.jpg),subs(aux,coeff(todd(b),t,i)*2^i) mod 2)) end
>   do;

Executing such code we obtain

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an application of the formula for $v_9$, we will prove the following lemma:

Let $Y^{19}$ be an orientable nineteen-manifold.  Then we have
$w_{19}(Y^{19}) =w_{18}(Y^{19})=w_{17}(Y^{19}) = 0 $.

Proof.  From the properties of the Wu classes we obtain for $Y^{19}$ that

$$\left\{ v_{{10}}=0,v_{{11}}=0,v_{{12}}=0,v_{{13}}=0,v_{{14}}=0,v_{{15}}=0,
 v_{{16}}=0,v_{{17}}=0,v_{{18}}=0,v_{{19}}=0\right\}$$

Now from the Wu’s formula, we derive that
$$w_{{19}}=0$$
$$w_{{18}}={v_{{9}}}^{2}$$
$$w_{{17}}={\it Sq}^{{8}} \left( v_{{9}} \right) $$

From other side we know that

$$v_{{9}}=w_{{1}}w_{{8}}+w_{{7}}{w_{{1}}}^{2}+w_{{6}}{w_{{1}}}^{3}+w_{{5
}}{w_{{1}}}^{4}+w_{{1}}{w_{{4}}}^{2}+w_{{4}}{w_{{1}}}^{5}+w_{{3}}{w_{{
1}}}^{6}+w_{{1}}{w_{{2}}}^{4}+{w_{{2}}}^{2}{w_{{1}}}^{5}+w_{{2}}{w_{{1
}}}^{7}+w_{{6}}w_{{1}}w_{{2}}+w_{{5}}w_{{1}}w_{{3}}+w_{{4}}w_{{3}}{w_{
{1}}}^{2}+w_{{3}}w_{{2}}{w_{{1}}}^{4}
$$

but given that $Y^{19}$ is orientable, it is to say $w_1 =0$; we obtain that $v_9=0$.
For hence we have that

$$w_{{19}}=0$$
$$w_{{18}}={v_{{9}}}^{2} = 0^2 = 0$$
$$w_{{17}}={\it Sq}^{{8}} \left( v_{{9}} \right)= {\it Sq}^{{8}} \left( 0\right)=0 $$

And then our lemma is proved.

Do you agree?

Comment: Looks fine, and this result corresponds to Theorem III in Massey's "On the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a manifold", https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372878?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents. (The result states that $w_n = w_{n-1} = w_{n-2} = 0$ for an oriented $n$-manifold if $n = 4k+3$.) It's also useful to note that every odd-indexed Wu class of an orientable manifold is 0.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic  many thanks for the link, the paper by Massey looks very interesting.  Your observations are very worthwhile.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic, I am observing that Massey presents the mentioned theorem as "Theorem III" on page 94.  Massey says that the proof of theorem III is presented at section 3 but I can not find it. Please can you say me where is the proof? Many thanks.

Comment: See the last paragraph of Section 3. He says he is proving Theorem II, but it is really Theorem III being proved.

Comment: @AleksandarMilivojevic, yes, you are right.  There is a typo in the last paragraph of Section 3.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As  Aleksandar Milivojevic is noting, Theorem III in Massey's "On the Stiefel-Whitney classes of a manifold", is formulated as

Let $Y^{4k + 3}$ be an orientable (4k+3)-manifold.  Then we have
$w_{4k+3}(Y^{4k+3}) =w_{4k+2}(Y^{4k+3})=w_{4k+1}(Y^{4k+2}) = 0 $.

Proof.  From the properties of the Wu classes we obtain for $Y^{4k+3}$ that

$$\left\{ v_{{2k+2}}=0,v_{{2k+3}}=0,v_{{2k+4}}=0,....,v_{{4k+3}}=0\right\}$$

Now from the Wu’s formula, we derive that
$$w_{{4k+3}}=0$$
$$w_{{4k+2}}={v_{{2k + 1}}}^{2}$$
$$w_{{4k+1}}={\it Sq}^{{2k}} \left( v_{{2k+1}} \right) $$

From other side, given that $Y^{4k+3}$ is orientable, we have that

$$v_{{2k+1}}=0$$.

For hence we have that

$$w_{{4k+3}}=0$$
$$w_{{4k+2}}={v_{{2k+1}}}^{2} = 0^2 = 0$$
$$w_{{4k+1}}={\it Sq}^{{2k}} \left( v_{{2k+1}} \right)= {\it Sq}^{{2k}} \left( 0\right)=0 $$

And then, the Massey`s theorem  is proved.